# Product variation quantity math

Tags: 7, commerce, rules

I have (4) four different product variations in product display: 3, 7, 10 and 14. Each of them has own price.

I would like to have that maximum that could be bought is 14. If someone buy 7 then there is only 3 and 7 variation left.

Or if there is still 14 left and someone buys 3 then there is 10, 7 and 3 left.

So value 14 should never be exceed.

Is this mission impossible? Any help is needed. Thanks!

Comment: Nothing is impossible... But could you clarify the question? This "14" is it per cart? per user? on the whole site?

Comment: It is for whole site - not user related. So example after there has been bought 10 and 3 - there is left 1 but it is not possible to buy that. After that product will be removed from site manually or automaticly - if possible.

Comment: I tryed Commerce Stock -module but it did not provide functionality what I'm looking for. But I'm thinking that could this module be used somehow in my case..?

Comment: Hmm, this could be done if I could set one stock value for all variations. So stock value would be groupped for all variations. Then using Rules to set rule which takes certain amount off the stock when buying certain variation.

But how to make same stock value for all variations?

Comment: Whilst I don't necessarily understand what you mean by the numbers 3, 7, 10 and 14 and how they are different I think I get the principle of what you want to do. I found [this module code](http://www.agileadam.com/add-to-cart-tweaks) a while back for a similar scenario I wanted to implement, in effect it allowed me to remove the add to cart functionality for specific products. It *sounds* like what you want to